# Issues: posting a wordpress website post link on a facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook

Good day, when I try to share a link on Facebook from my website rasina.com.ua - Facebook tells me that the page doesn't exist. [image: rd]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some cache issue.

I would recommend to debug the url with the facebook developer tool:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?locale=de_DE

It only takes a view seconds and should show you all the meta information, facebook is getting from your website.